# CakePHP 2.4.9 saveAssociated from "belongsTo Model" - Strange Record Issue

Tags: cakephp, records

Here's the relation info:

1. global_products hasMany inventory_products
2. inventory_products belongsTo global_products

I've running this save call from my controller

```
$options = array('deep' => true);
if($this->InventoryProduct->saveAssociated($this->request->data, $options)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully added products');
}
else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Failed to add products');
}
```

Here's the contents of $this->request->data just before the save

```
Array
(
    [GlobalProduct] => Array
        (
            [upc] => 111222333444
            [brand] => Sample Brand
            [name] => Sample Name
            [InventoryProduct] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [purchase_price] => 10.00
                            [sale_price] => 15.00
                            [practice_id] => 35
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [purchase_price] => 10.00
                            [sale_price] => 15.00
                            [practice_id] => 35
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And here's the resulting tables entries

1. global_products

   - id = x // Note: x is defined by database (auto-increment field)
   - upc = 111222333444
   - brand = Sample Brand
   - name = Sample Name
2. inventory_products

   - purchase_price = 10.00
   - sale_price = 15.00
   - global_product_id = x
3. inventory_products

   - purchase_price = 10.00
   - sale_price = 15.00
   - global_product_id = x
4. inventory_products

   - purchase_price = 0
   - sale_price = 0
   - global_product_id = x

**I can't seem to figure out for the life of me why a 3rd inventory_product record is being created when only 2 inventory_records are present in the save data array.**

I've been staring over this code for hours and I'm not seeing the issue. I'm sure it's probably something stupid. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is the combination of saving on the associated model and using the `deep` option.

Using `deep` should only be necessary for non-direct associations, something like saving a new post with comments including new users in a `Post hasMany Comment belongsTo User` association. The `User` is a non-direct association and would require using `deep`, the direct associated `Comment` entries however would not.

Also you should save on the main model instead, that is `GlobalProduct`, and your data should then be formatted differently according to the CakePHP conventions, that is `InventoryProduct` should not be nested in `GlobalProduct`.

Long story short, normally this should do it:

```
$this->InventoryProduct->GlobalProduct->saveAssociated($this->request->data)
```

where the data should be formatted like this:

```
Array
(
    [GlobalProduct] => Array
        (
            [upc] => 111222333444
            [brand] => Sample Brand
            [name] => Sample Name

        )
    [InventoryProduct] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [purchase_price] => 10.00
                    [sale_price] => 15.00
                    [practice_id] => 35
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [purchase_price] => 10.00
                    [sale_price] => 15.00
                    [practice_id] => 35
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: I've gone ahead converted everything to what you said and it's working perfectly. Thank you. 

Out of curiosity, is it possible to save this data from the child model or is it always required to save from the parent model?

Comment: Just noticed your comment @user3671307, it might be possible in some situations to save via a child model, but I'm not sure whether this is officially supported, so I'd avoid it and always save from the top most model of your data/association structure that is to be saved.